# IOS - Drag and drop item from gmail attachment

Tags: swift, ipad, drag-and-drop

i'm trying to develop an app where user is able to drag a pdf attachment from gmail (web version on safari) and drop it on the developed app
It seems that the issue is related from the attachment type while i'm sure that it is a pdf file
Even when i try to drag the pdf file from downloads it doesn't seem to work and nothing on the terminal output

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDropInteractionDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var destinationView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addInteraction(UIDropInteraction(delegate: self))
    }
    
    func customEnableDropping(on view: UIView, dropInteractionDelegate: UIDropInteractionDelegate) {
        let dropInteraction = UIDropInteraction(delegate: dropInteractionDelegate)
        view.addInteraction(dropInteraction)
    }
    
    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: NSURL.self)
    }
    
    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
        for dragItem in session.items {
            print("Dropped item type identifiers:", dragItem.itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers)
            dragItem.itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.data", options: nil) { obj, err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to load item:", err)
                }
                if let data = obj as? Data {
                    let header = String(data: data.prefix(8), encoding: .utf8)
                    print("PDF Header:", header)
                }

                if let data = obj as? Data {
                    print("Loaded data size:", data.count)
                    do {
                        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(data: data) {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.displayPDFDocument(pdfDocument)
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to create PDFDocument from data.")
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Error creating PDFDocument:", error)
                    }

                }
            }



        }
    }
    
    func displayPDFDocument(_ pdfDocument: PDFDocument) {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        pdfView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        destinationView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        destinationView.addSubview(pdfView)
        pdfView.frame = destinationView.bounds
    }
    
    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
        return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
    }
}
```

Output i'm getting when i try to drop a pdf file on the developed app from gmail

```
Dropped item type identifiers: ["public.url", "public.utf8-plain-text"]
PDF Header: Optional("bplist00")
Loaded data size: 396
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
Failed to create PDFDocument from data.
```